# Closed sets and how they relate to open balls?

Tags: metric-spaces

Is it correct to say:

If a set $A$ has a point $x$ such that for all $r>0$, the open ball of radius $r$, centered at $x$ is not a subset of $A$, then $A$ must be a closed set.

Comment: Unfortunately not, this only implies $A$ is not open.

Comment: @JulienGodawatta

Interesting. So in real analysis, "not open" is not the same as "closed"? I thought 'open' and 'closed' were negations of each other :(   

Does this mean that there can be a set that is not open nor closed?

Comment: Indeed, unfortunate terminology. Sets can be open, closed, neither, or both ("clopen").

Comment: @JulienGodawatta

Hmm. Good thing I didn't end up relying on this in my homework. Thank you for the info!

Comment: @JulienGodawatta It may be useful for you to know that the complement of a closed set is open.

Comment: Some familiar examples on the real line: $(0,1)$ is open, $[0,1]$ is closed, $[0,1)$ is neither open nor closed, and $\mathbb{R}$ is both open and closed.

Comment: The condition says that $x$ is a limit point of $X\setminus A$, the complement of $A$. *This implies that the complement is not closed*, otherwise $x$ would be in that set whereas it's in $A$. Therefore $A$ is not open. But you can't conclude that $A$ is closed: Re your question above — correct: "not open" $\ne$ "closed". What **is** true is that the complement of an open set is closed, and the complement of a closed set is open: $A$ is closed [resp. open] *iff* $X\setminus A$ is open [resp. closed].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been said in the comments, your formulation is not quite correct.

Here is something that you can say:

$A$ is closed iff, for each $x \not \in A$, there is a $r > 0$ so that $B_r(x)$ does not intersect $A$.

Hint for proof: Try to show that $A^c$ is open. Show that the complement of an open set is closed. (And conversely, the complement of an open set is closed.)

Further relevant exercises, related to the comments: 1) Show that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\emptyset$ are both both open and closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Generalize this to a general metric space. 2) Find a metric space in which every subset is both closed and open. 3) Describe the open and closed sets in $\mathbb{Q}$ 4) Describe the closed and open sets in the Cantor set.